# What's the best way to train data with unbalanced targets?

Tags: supervised-learning, multi-label-classification, imbalanced-datasets

Suppose I have data I want to use for supervised learning, but there is a pretty bad target/class/labels imbalance. Should I:

1. Limit the size of the training set to make sure there is a flat target/class balance distribution (the training set is designed such that there is an equal number of training samples for each class based on splitting the lowest-occuring class as high as possible). For example, if my lowest-occuring class appears only 50 times in my data, and I want an 80-20 train-test split, then I decide I take 40 of the samples for training, and for an even target balance, take 40 samples for all other samples in training, even if the highiest-occuring class appears 100,000 times, for instance.
2. Ignore target balance and just focus on the ratio for the train and testing split. So, if it's 80-20, take 40 of the samples out of 50 for my lowest-occuring class, and 80% of 100,000 for my highest occuring class, and so on.
3. Something else?

Let's suppose I can't just get more data. I know there's some stuff to be said regarding undersampling and oversampling, but what can I do to tell if either one is working better if model accuracy might be disingenuous?

Comment: What I would advise is to try and get a representative training set for your test and application set. If your eventual application is also heavily imbalanced, then it makes sense for your train/test sets to also be unbalanced. You have to realise that if your application also is unbalanced, it is much more important to correctly classify/predict the biggest category than the smaller ones, so it makes sense to represent this in the train/test set. Do pay attention to also make your test set and training set 'similarly unbalanced'

Comment: If your final application data is balanced, I would probably try to get my training/test sets to be balanced as well